# Dynamic Border Div not showing at all

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, border

I'm having difficulty using a div as a border. I have a main and a sidebar div at either side of it and I'm trying to set the height of the border div to the height of either the height of the main div or the sidebar div depending on which is greater.

I have tried looking at similar-ish height problems here but I can't make them work. [This is the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeey0h5p/).

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar height">
            <div class="sidebar-inner">
                <img class="logo-sidebar" src="img/logo.jpg" />
                <img class="img-sidebar" src="img/pic1.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border"></div>
        <div class="main border-inner height">
            <div class="main-inner">
                <img class="img" src="img/pic7.jpg" style="height: 300px;" />

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
max-width: 926px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #66AB98;
color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 26.1%;
    padding-bottom: 2000px;
    margin-bottom: -2000px;
    display: block;
}

.sidebar-inner {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 30px 2%;
}

.main {
    float: right;
    width: 73%;
    padding-bottom: 2000px;
    margin-bottom: -2000px;
    display: block;
}

.main-inner {
    width: 96%;
    margin: 30px 2%;
}

.border {
    float: left;
    width: .5%;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 30px 0;
}

p {
    text-indent: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

.img {
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}


/*---------------------
        Sidebar
---------------------*/

.logo-sidebar {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
}

.img-sidebar {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 20px 5% 0 5%;
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var height - main = $(".main").height();
  var height - sidebar = $(".sidebar").height();

  if (height - main > height - sidebar) {
    $(".border").css("height", height - main);
  } else if (height - main < height - sidebar) {
    $(".border").css("height", height - sidebar);
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a div as a border? - Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are invalid. In JS, variable names cannot contain a `-` as it's the subtraction operator. Remove that and your code works, for example:

```
var mainHeight = $(".main").height();
var sidebarHeight = $(".sidebar").height();

if (mainHeight > sidebarHeight) {
    $(".border").css("height", mainHeight);
} else if (mainHeight < sidebarHeight) {
    $(".border").css("height", sidebarHeight);
}
```

Also note that you can make the code simpler by removing the `if` statement and using `Math.max()`, like this:

```
var mainHeight = $(".main").height();
var sidebarHeight = $(".sidebar").height();
$(".border").css("height", Math.max(mainHeight, sidebarHeight));
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qeey0h5p/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much that works! You've saved me hours of work from being wasted! :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why are you using JavaScript for such a simple task, while you can do it easily with just CSS.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 926px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #66AB98;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  left: 26.25%;
  content: '';
  width: 3px;
  bottom: 28px;
  top: 28px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 26.1%;
  padding-bottom: 2000px;
  margin-bottom: -2000px;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar-inner {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 30px 2%;
}

.main {
  float: right;
  width: 73%;
}

.main-inner {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 30px 2%;
}

.border {
  float: left;
  width: .5%;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

p {
  text-indent: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

.img {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}


/*---------------------
Sidebar
---------------------*/

.logo-sidebar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
}

.img-sidebar {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px 5% 0 5%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar height">
    <div class="sidebar-inner">
      <img class="logo-sidebar" src="img/logo.jpg" />
      <img class="img-sidebar" src="img/pic1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="border"></div>
  <div class="main border-inner height">
    <div class="main-inner">
      <img class="img" src="img/pic7.jpg" style="height: 300px;" />

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a mill i wasn't sure how to do it. Could you explain the :before part because I'm not sure what it does. thanks!

Comment: @james We use `position: relative` on parent element with `top` and `bottom` properties with `position: absolute` on pseudo element like `:before` or `:after`. In this way pseudo element will get full height according to parent's height. When a child element whether it is sidebar or main content will grow, it will increase the height of parent element and as a result height of pseudo element will also grow.